# How to change multi filter operators with a brief solution, in Rx Js observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to write this code with a relatively short code, can you advise some solution?
Thanks!

```
fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
filter(e => e.target !== this.one.nativeElement),
filter(e => e.target !== this.two.nativeElement),
filter(e => e.target !== this.three.nativeElement),
map(() => console.log('target'))
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  filter(e => ![
    this.one.nativeElement, 
    this.two.nativeElement, 
    this.three.nativeElement
  ].some(elem => e.target === elem)),
  map(() => console.log('target'))
).subscribe();
```